# TypeError Using regex and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im working on some code that is reading a html, being parsed by beautifulsoup, and then want to use regex to find some numbers (part of an assignment).

Now an earlier assignment I used socket instead of urllib and I know that the error is from data types (expecting string or bytes) but down the line Im missing what I need to encode/decode to process the data. The error occurs at my re.findall

Besides a fix, what is causing the issue, and I guess more importantly what are the data type differences because I seem to be missing something... that should feel inherent.

Thanks ahead.

```
#Py3 urllib is utllib.request
import urllib.request

#BeautifulSoup stuff bs4 in Py3
from bs4 import *

#Raw Input now input in Py3
#url = 'http://' + input('Enter - ')
url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html')

html = url.read()

#html.parser is the parser that defaults. Usefull most of the time (according to the web)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
# Retrieve all of the tags specified
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:

    print(re.findall('[0-9]+', tag))
```

Comment: Exactly, What do you doing?, because re not define on your code and you reggex expression match all numbers, You should import the module re for that work fine.

Comment: Did not copy that yes import re is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've been caught off guard with this before: BeautifulSoup returns objects, which just appear to be strings when you call `print`.

Just as a sanity check, try this:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import *

url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.read(), 'html.parser')
single_tag = soup('span')[0]
print("Type is: \"%s\"; prints as \"%s\"" % (type(single_tag), single_tag))
print("As a string: \"%s\"; prints as \"%s\"" % (type(str(single_tag)), str(single_tag)))
```

The following should be output:

> Type is: "< class 'bs4.element.Tag' >"; prints as "< span
>   class="comments" >97< /span >"
>       As a string: "< class 'str' >"; prints as "< span class="comments" >97< /span >"

So, if you encapsulate "tag" in a `str()` call before sending it to the regex, that problem should be taken care of

I've always found that adding sanity `print(type(var))` checks when things start to complain about unexpected variable types to be a useful debugging technique!

Comment: Sanity check helped big time. First foray into bs4 and could not tell the print was just throwing the object back at me. Ill test when home ty